# C-Pic Counter issue

Tags: c, counter, microcontroller, pic

So the micro I am using is a PIC 18F.

If **Alarm_Status.bits.b3** is set which essentially is just a switch an alarm is created. The first snippet of code works as it should

```
BS(TRISB,7);                                // Bund sw port=input.
    DelayMs(2);                                 // will rise is bund SW open
    if(RB7){
        if(Control.bits.BUND_ENABLE){           // if bund alarm enabled
            if(Alarm_Status.bits.b3){           // if  already set
                DU_Reason.bits.EmergencyDialIn=1;   // alarm!
            }
        }
        Alarm_Status.bits.b3=0;                 // Bund Sw Open
    }
    else Alarm_Status.bits.b3=1;                // Bund Sw Closed
    BC(TRISB,7);
```

However I want to alarm only if the switch is set for a certain period of time instead of when the switch is set straight away.The function is called every second. Could anyone point me in the direction od where I am going wrong.

```
        int count = 0;
        int fixedCount = 20;
        BS(TRISB,7);                            // Bund sw port=input.
        DelayMs(2);                             // will rise is bund SW open
        if(RB7){                                
            if(Control.bits.BUND_ENABLE){       // if bund alarm enabled
                if(Alarm_Status.bits.b3){       // if  already set
                    count +=10;                 //count increased by 10
                }
                    if(count == fixedCount) {
                        DU_Reason.bits.EmergencyDialIn=1;// alarm!
                        count = 0;
                    }
            }
            Alarm_Status.bits.b3=0;             // Bund Sw Open
        }
        else
            count = 0;
            Alarm_Status.bits.b3=1;     // Bund Sw Closed
            BC(TRISB,7);
```

Comment: `count` variable should be global.

Comment: "Bund" is not English, is it? Seems like an important word.

Comment: Shows what you know bund is english did you ever hear of a bund sensor, obviously not. Anyway thanks Alex declaring it globally worked just fine cheers.

Comment: @Alex Farber or NewLook.  Suggest posting an answer and accepting it to close this post.

Comment: C is not Python - indentation is irrelevant. The last three lines in your second block are indented as if they should be executed in the `else` block but they are not enclosed in braces (`{ }`). Thus only `count = 0;` is specific to the `else` case. The other two lines run every time.

Answer (score 1):

You can make that `count` as static. Problem with current code, after every instance, count gets re-initialized to 0 and hence, it will never reach to `fixedCount`

If you modify your code as:

```
#define FIXED_COUNT 20    //Why to waste memory??

void PollSwitch()
{
    static int count = 0;

    BS(TRISB,7);                            // Bund sw port=input.
    DelayMs(2);                             // will rise is bund SW open

    if(RB7)
     {                                
       if(Control.bits.BUND_ENABLE){             // if bund alarm enabled
          if(Alarm_Status.bits.b3){       // if  already set
                        count +=10;                 //count increased by 10
             }
            if(count == FIXED_COUNT ) {
                 DU_Reason.bits.EmergencyDialIn=1;// alarm!
                 count = 0;
                 Alarm_Status.bits.b3=0;             //Alarm is raised, Open switch
              }
        }
               // Alarm_Status.bits.b3=0;          // Bund Sw Open <<< NOT NEEDED, IMO
     }
    else
     {
         count = 0;
         Alarm_Status.bits.b3=1;     // Bund Sw Closed
     }
        BC(TRISB,7);    
}
```